# Логи не выводятся на телефоне, но выводятся на планшете

Tags: android, android-studio

В Andoid Studio пытаюсь вывести логи с помощью `Log.d()`, тестирую через телефон- логи не выводятся. Отсоединяю телефон, подключаю планшет, тестирую - логи выводятся прекрасно.

Может быть в каких-то настройках самого устройства причина? кто-нибудь знает в каких?

Результат команды *#*#2846579#*#*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не huawei случаем?

Comment: @post_zeew да. На huawei именно логи не вывело, а на lenovo вывело

Answer (score 1):

На некоторых устройствах Huawei логи по-умолчанию отключены.

Чтобы их включить, наберите:

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

Далее `Background Setting` – `Log setting`, и там включите логи.

Comment: странно, у меня после этой команды совсем другое меню, где нельзя ничего менять, можно только посмотреть информацию вроде "заблокирована ли сим?" нажимаешь, и выдается диалоговое окно "нет, не заблокирована" и вот в таком роде все пункты, никаких логов там нет...

Comment: @Farad, Покажите скриншот.

Comment: добавил. Первый скрин это то что я вижу при вводе команды. Далее 4 скрина по одному на каждый из пунктов.

Comment: @Farad, А какая модель телефона?

Comment: HUAWEI Y6 Pro..